# MUI How to add text with textfield input props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I have a text field with InputProps which is a icon that triggers an onClick

```
        <TextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Type Tag Name"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: <AddIcon sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={(e) => handleTagAdd(e)} />,
      }}
    />
```

the handleTagAdd function will add e.target.value to some state, however I am getting undefined values when I console.log e.target.value

Is it not the event from the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

`endAdornment` is a div that contains a button. Therefore this HTML element doesn't have a value property and `e.target.value` returns `undefined`.